# Git Log in ZSH Terminal

Tags: git, terminal, zsh

I remember in a Git-tutorial video that the user's terminal (probably ZSH) was split into two; one for the standard terminal commands, and below that there was something like Git log graphical representation. It was always visible at the bottom of the terminal with nice colors.

[image: terminal screen].

How is it possible to split the terminal screen into two and display Git log (something like `git log --pretty=format:'%h : %s' --graph`) on the terminal screen?

UPDATE: I found the video on Vimeo, http://vimeo.com/16018419. I am trying to do the exact same setup on my ZSH terminal.

Comment: From the video it looks like he's doing the window split in GNU screen. If you look around 6:28, he also has to manually refresh the display somehow. You could accomplish that just by doing a standard screen split and hitting q / up to rerun the command; you could also probably run it in a loop to do that automatically every 10 seconds or whatever.

Comment: Yes, seems like he is refreshing manually. At this point, I can go with manual refresh, no problem. Are you sure about splitting the GNU screen? I think he is doing something else. If you look at the scrollbar at the right, it covers from top to bottom. And he is refreshing, not writing a shell command. I don't know, maybe you are right but I think he is doing something different.

Comment: If you look at the terminal titlebar, it says screen in it, and those status lines look like screen to me. And the scrollbar is in Terminal.app / iTerm.app, not screen, so it makes sense that it'd cover the full thing. I'm not sure how he's refreshing (you're right that it's not rerunning a shell command), but re-running should have the same effect...maybe he has a background process writing out to a file and is doing some editor incantation to reload the file (or just re-run the command inside the editor), not sure.

Comment: You might be right, but what about refreshing? He is not writing any commands, he is just refreshing. Is it possible to refresh a terminal window? I will try to figure it out how he is refreshing.

Comment: You can't refresh a terminal window (it's not at all clear what that means). He's presumably doing some kind of editor command, maybe a vim mapping or whatever, that's rerunning a command, or possibly reloading a file that another command is writing to in the background. In any case, I don't know why it matters that you have exactly the same setup when you can get the same effect by mapping `:!git log ..... > %` to a keystroke in vim.

Comment: True but I just wondered if he was using a special application. I just found him on Twitter. He replied and said that he was using tmux (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: FYI, Mark, author of the video at vimeo, explains in the comments below the video that he uses iTerm2 which comes wit tmux support. So, @josh-mcgee solution should be perfect fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

with tmux, you can split-pane `zsh -c while :; do sleep 60; git log ...; done` and this should achieve an automagically refreshing git log output in a pane.

supply [-vh] [percent] to split-pane to split vert or horiz with a given percent of the terminal. iirc, it splits from bottom and/or right side of terminal, so adjust percentage accordingly.

this should have the desired effect of having git log in a pane beside $EDITOR (or below), with appropriate dimensions and automagically refresh every minute. feel free to alter or clean up syntax to suit your needs.

EDIT:
respawning a pane in tmux can be done with the tmux builtin `respawn-pane`. you can bind a key something like this to get a simple shortcut

bind-key -n M-r respawn-pane -t git:0.1 [command]

in this example, i assume 3 things. first, that you have a named tmux session (named git, but this is arbitrary and to your choosing by using `rename-session` in tmux or by launching the session with `new-session -s name`). second, that the git log (which is what we want to refresh) is at window of index 0 (this is the first window opened in a session, by default, unless you set `base-index` to else) and the pane of index 1.

so here, it respawns the second pane of the first window in the "git" session by pressing alt-r. if you use the loop i provided before, this is unnecessary to do because the log will refresh itself after each sleep. that may be considered wasteful to some, so you may arbitrarily decide to respawn this pane at your whim instead.

[command] is optional. tmux's `respawn-pane` will execute the command that was given when the pane was spawned at first. in this example, it will be the `while` loop by default. if you skip the loop and instead just use `split-pane [-hv] [percent] "git log ..."` then do not provide the optional command parameter as the pane will run it for you smartly. providing the command parameter to `respawn-pane` will take precedence over the initial command used when spawning the pane.

finally, if you do not provide the command parameter to `split-pane` initially, tmux will run whatever value `default-command` is.

so there you have an overly verbose explanation of how to do what this video does in multiple ways.

Answer (score 2):

`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --color=always` for the git log output.

The terminal splitting feature depends on your console.

Comment: I know the Git log command. I use ZSH on both Ubuntu 12 and Mac OS X 1.7 and I was looking for splitting terminal into two and displaying that Git log at the bottom of the terminal. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @BurakErdem your question seems to belong to SuperUser then.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

he is using iTerm on Mac, the split is made by default, You just need to go on menu or use any short command. You can take this with terminator on ubuntu/linux. If you want to continue using gnome-terminal, you can use screen or tmux to simulate this.

In log, he is using tig (http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/): a git browsing tool. It can be installed easy easy. By the way you can use watch to auto update your log, so you can have an "autolog" on another part of your terminal. ;)

```
watch git log --graph
```

Here, I'm using tmux in my console:

[image: Using tmux with some applications]